# umask is not working for directories

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, nfs, umask

I have an odd problem with umask.
My current setting is:

```
$ umask
0022
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
```

This only works for files though and not directories:

```
$ touch abc
$ ll abc
0 -rw-rw-rw- 1 user1 group1 0 Dec 12 11:39 abc
$ mkdir def
$ ll -d def
8.0K drwxrwxrwx+ 2 user1 group1 4.0K Dec 12  2012 def
```

Can anybody suggest why umask is not working for the directory? Any help is appreciated!

This is a new Centos linux system.

Edit: thanks for the comments. As some have pointed out, this doesn't work for files either.

Extra information: This problem only seems to occur on the home directory which is mounted over NFS, and not on local directories. Could NFS be causing the problem somehow?

Comment: abc's perm is not right either.  it should be -rw-r--r--

Comment: You're right - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you repeat these tests in the /tmp directory?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're problem is that you have access control list getting applied here as well. Notice the directory, def? It has a trailing '+' which means that there is `ACL` permissions getting applied here as well. Can you run the command `getfacl` at your `$HOME` directory level? This will give us more insight into what's going on.

For example:

```
% getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

Answer (score 0):

Directories have execution permission unless you disable it explicitly. Try umask 0033 if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `umask` is not work at all.

For file, the `touch` command will create with `-rw-rw-rw-` and the `umask` is `0022`, then after mask `0666 & ~ 0022`. The final permission will be `0644 (-rw-r--r--)`. So it does not work for file either.

For directory, the `mkdir` command will create with `rwxrwxrwx` and the `umask` is `0022`, then after mask `0777 & ~ 0022`. The final permission will be `0755 (rwxr-xr-x)`.

But I do not know why does it not work. Maybe it is the problem of your SHELL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you're right - the file is not set correctly either. I'm wondering if NFS is the problem (see edit above), but I don't understand the connection to umask in that regard.